# Sci-fi novel, scout crash lands on planet, shaman sees competition and wrecks spherical spaceship

Tags: story-identification, spaceship

I read this years ago. A scout in spherical advanced ship lands on a planet. Natives are friendly, but the shaman perceives competition, and sneaks into the craft and scatters potions on the controls, their acid eating into plastics and metals. He can be rescued at the other side of planet, but he has a deadline. Eventually all make airship and he makes it.

Comment: Are you saying that the tribe made an airship? And how many years ago? If you can go to https://scifi.stackexchange.com/tags/story-identification/info, and answer as many questions as you can, it will help us help you.

Answer (score 18):

[The Flying Sorcerors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Flying_Sorcerers) by Niven and Gerrold is a humorous novel which has many elements in common with your description.  One of the characters is a thinly disguised Isaac Asimov who conflicts with the native sorcerer for prestige. The native "magic" is based on potions, corrosive liquids, use of native animals, etc. His ship is destroyed in the conflict, and they do end up constructing an airship.

His egg-shaped (close to spherical!) spaceship is shown on this cover.

[image]

Comment: I remember Willville and Orbur, and their adventures with "Purple"

Comment: That's it! Fast answer. Loaned it to someone long since forgotten and never saw it again. Thank you.

Comment: @MikeB You seem to have created a [new account](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/97418/mikeb) here which is different from your [original account](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/97411/mikeb). Please consider following [these instructions](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts) to **merge your accounts** so that you can regain access to the original account and **accept this answer** to mark it as correct. Thanks, and glad we could help you find your answer! :-)

Comment: I _think_ there were other characters who were "thinly disguised" scifi authors - can't remember why I think that - but if anyone agrees a list would be nice!

Comment: The authors were the gods in the local religion - N'veen the god of tides etc.

Comment: And Caff, the goddess of dragons...

Comment: Complete list found (where else?) https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Flying_Sorcerers