# Primitive species destroy travelers shuttle

Tags: story-identification, spaceship

Trying to identify a story where an explorer/academian lands on a primitive world and the native witch doctor destroys the shuttle, preventing the explorer from returning to his mothership. He ends up traveling to polar area to regain contact with mothership.

Comment: Hi there! Could you provide us a bit more info? For instance, what kind of story is that - short story, full-fledged novel? When did you read it? Was it in English, was it a tranlsation?

Comment: Not much to go on. The Flying Sorcerors by Niven and Gerrold? https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/182785/sci-fi-novel-scout-crash-lands-on-planet-shaman-sees-competition-and-wrecks-sp/182786#182786

Comment: Gotta be them Flying Sorcerors.  Does the color purple mean anything to you?