# Astronaut studying aliens is mistaken for a wizard

Tags: story-identification, books

This book was about an astronaut studying an alien race. The alien village leader thinks he's a wizard or warlock, he also thinks the astronaut is a monster there to attack them. He uses ordinary things to make his magic and cause problems for the astronaut who's just there to study them.

Comment: Welcome to Science Fiction & Fantasy! This question would be improved by going through the checklists here; [How to ask a good story-ID question?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question)

Comment: Closure note: both answers accepted via comments.

Answer (score 20):

I think that may be [*The Flying Sorcerers*](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Flying_Sorcerers) by Larry Niven and David Gerrold.

> The plot concerns the efforts of an astronaut and
>   geologist/anthropologist, known to the natives as "Purple", to escape
>   from a primitive world on which he is stranded and return to his
>   people. The events are seen from the perspective of Lant, one of the
>   natives, who becomes, in the course of the novel, Speaker (chieftain)
>   of his people.
>
> The natives, a fur covered people, believe in magic and the book shows
>   how sufficiently advanced technology would be perceived by a primitive
>   society.
>
> Purple lands in an egg-shaped vehicle. He casually disrupts the lives
>   of Lant's people, and thoughtlessly demeans Shoogar, the village
>   magician. Shoogar gets revenge by destroying Purple's vehicle, which
>   results in an atomic explosion. Many of the villagers are dead or
>   injured: the rest, including Lant and Shoogar, are forced to flee.
>   Purple is presumed dead.

Shoogar does indeed use ordinary things to destroy Purple’s vehicle.

Comment: If confirmed, it's a duplicate of https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/182785/sci-fi-novel-scout-crash-lands-on-planet-shaman-sees-competition-and-wrecks-sp/182786#182786 (which was accepted via comment)

Comment: That's it, thanks so much. Merry Christmas